# Open json file link through a code

Tags: python, json

I'm creating an addon and I'm modifying some functions that come within a py file.
What I intend to do is the following, I have this code:

```js
def channellist():
    return json.loads(openfile('lib.json',pastafinal=os.path.join(tugapath,'resources')))
```

This code gives access to a lib.json file that is inside the tugapath folder in the resources subfolder. What I did was put the lib.json file in the dropbox and wanted to replace it with the dropbox link from the lib.json file instead of calling the folders.

I tried to change the code but without success.

```js
def channellist():
    return json.loads(openfile('lib.json',pastafinal=os.path.join("https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj1246qtiodm6qd/lib.json?dl=1')))
```

If someone can help me, I'm grateful! 
Thank you first.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What's the `openfile` method? what's that `pastafinal` option?

Comment: @QuantumLicht Folder will call the file lib.json that is inside the folder tugapath and subfolder resources. What I wanted was instead of calling lib.json that is inside this folder call what is in the dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj1246qtiodm6qd/lib.json?dl=1

Comment: There's a big difference between opening a file on local disk and one that is stored on a remote server. Chances are your openfile method cannot handle that.

Comment: @QuantumLicht Is there any way I can call the link I want using something similar? I can pass the py file if you want. I already walk the hours looking for solution and nothing

Comment: Yes, you need to provide more context. That's how you get an answer here on stackoverflow

Comment: @QuantumLicht I adapted it in ftp mode. I have this document which is where all the codes are, including what I intend to replace http://radiojoven.6te.net/default.py. Basically there is such a folder where the file lib.json http://radiojoven.6te.net/resources/lib.json. What I intend is to call lib.json not from such a folder but from the dropbox and if I can use the better link yet.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your link holds valid json - which is not the case with the content you posted - you could use requests.

If the content at dropbox looked liked this:

```
{"tv": 
    {"epg": "tv",
    "streams": 
        [{"url": "http://topchantv.net:3456/live/Stalker/Stalker/838.m3u8", 
        "name": "IPTV", 
        "resolve": False, 
        "visible": True}], 
    "name": "tv", 
    "thumb": "thumb_tv.png"
    }
}
```

Then fetching the content would be like this

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj1246qtiodm6qd/lib.json?dl=1'
r = requests.get(url)
json_object = r.json()
```

So if you needed it inside a function, I guess you'd input the url and return the json like so:

```
def channellist(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_object = r.json()
    return json_object
```

Comment: I've already been modifying in default.py as you mentioned and giving me an error. It may have been my fault, if not bothered, could you re-create the default.py page with your changes? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you paste in the error traceback? It's impossible to debug unknown errors...

Comment: Basically I replace what I had with what you advised me as you can see at this link http://radiojoven.6te.net/defaut2.py.

Comment: And which errors does that give you, when you run the script?